# "$count$ questions with new activity" が翻訳されなくなっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

トップぺージ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ に表示される "$count$ questions with new activity" が翻訳されなくなってしまっていました。

string はあるようです: https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3640

[image]

Comment: 他にもトップページの質問一覧で「○分前」の所が英語になったり日本語になったり、コメント欄周りも少し怪しいです。 / プロフィール (アクティビティ) ページのリニューアルがあったので、それに関連して翻訳周りがおかしくなってる気がします。

Comment: MSE にも投稿しました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スタッフからのアナウンスは特にありませんが、2022-02-02 現在、「更新があった場合の表示」と「クリックして読み込んだ後のタイムスタンプ」が日本語表示に戻っているようです。

Answer (score 3):

[`full.ja.js`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ja.js?v=edfca4a8bdbd) にある以下の関数により日時の更新が行われるとき、ソースコード中に書かれた英文が使われているようです（`$seconds$ secs ago`, `$minutes$ mins ago`, `$hours$ hours ago`）。これが原因で ja.traducir.win の翻訳も反映されないのだと思います。

```javascript
function P(t) {
    if (t) {
        var n = t.match(/^(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ)/);
        if (n) {
            var s = n[1] + "T" + n[2],
                a = new Date(s),
                i = ((new Date).getTime() - a.getTime()) / 1e3 + e.options.serverTimeOffsetSec,
                o = Math.floor(i / 86400);
            if (!(isNaN(o) || o < 0 || o >= 31))
                return 0 == o && (i < 2 && __tr(["たった今"], undefined, "ja", []) || i < 60 && (l ? __tr(["$seconds$s ago"], {
                    seconds: Math.floor(i)
                }, "ja", ["seconds"]) : __tr(["$seconds$ secs ago"], {
                    seconds: Math.floor(i)
                }, "ja", ["seconds"])) || i < 120 && (l ? __tr(["1 分前"], undefined, "ja", []) : __tr(["1 分前"], undefined, "ja", [])) || i < 3600 && (l ? __tr(["$minutes$m ago"], {
                    minutes: Math.floor(i / 60)
                }, "ja", ["minutes"]) : __tr(["$minutes$ mins ago"], {
                    minutes: Math.floor(i / 60)
                }, "ja", ["minutes"])) || i < 7200 && (l ? __tr(["1 時間前"], undefined, "ja", []) : __tr(["1 時間前"], undefined, "ja", [])) || i < 86400 && (l ? __tr(["$hours$h ago"], {
                    hours: Math.floor(i / 3600)
                }, "ja", ["hours"]) : __tr(["$hours$ hours ago"], {
                    hours: Math.floor(i / 3600)
                }, "ja", ["hours"])))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問文の画像についても、 `full.ja.js` に `$count$ questions with new activity` という英文が残っているので、同様の原因だと思います。